# How do I append SVG circle inside a tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg, appendchild

[image]The following circle tag is inside  tag:

```
<circle cx="111.70110487400142" cy="134.60212936975006" r="10" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" data-pdf-annotate-id="8e1b063b-ec08-4c73-8b86-d8e8cce5615e" data-pdf-annotate-type="fillcircle" aria-hidden="true" transform="scale(1.33) rotate(0) translate(0, 0)"></circle>
```

Now i have to append this generated circle inside a tag like

```
<a href="#">
<circle cx="111.70110487400142" cy="134.60212936975006" r="10" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" data-pdf-annotate-id="8e1b063b-ec08-4c73-8b86-d8e8cce5615e" data-pdf-annotate-type="fillcircle" aria-hidden="true" transform="scale(1.33) rotate(0) translate(0, 0)"></circle>
</a>
```

**Updated:**

```
<svg class="annotationLayer" width="1118.53" height="1582.7" data-pdf-annotate-container="true" data-pdf-annotate-viewport="{&quot;viewBox&quot;:[0,0,841,1190],&quot;scale&quot;:1.33,&quot;rotation&quot;:0,&quot;offsetX&quot;:0,&quot;offsetY&quot;:0,&quot;transform&quot;:[1.33,0,0,-1.33,0,1582.7],&quot;width&quot;:1118.53,&quot;height&quot;:1582.7,&quot;fontScale&quot;:1.33}" data-pdf-annotate-document="/uploads/docs/Vishnu/file/IBC-CW1a-DE-02_2.pdf" data-pdf-annotate-page="1" style="width: 1118.53px; height: 1582.7px;">

<circle cx="138.76877404693374" cy="82.72243012162977" r="10" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" data-pdf-annotate-id="b91a7011-656c-48d6-9f1c-62ac4bfc4f91" data-pdf-annotate-type="fillcircle" aria-hidden="true" transform="scale(1.33) rotate(0) translate(0, 0)"></circle>

</svg>


function createCircle(a) {
      var circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
      (0, _setAttributes2.default)(circle, {
        cx: a.cx,
        cy: a.cy,
        r: a.r
        });
        var spot_anchor = document.createElement("a")
        console.log(spot_anchor)
        spot_anchor.appendChild(circle)
        console.log(spot_anchor)

   console.log('Create_circl1')
      return circle;
    }
```

How can i able to do by using javascript ?

Comment: You need an `<svg>` tag - you can't just have SVG elements naked inside your HTML.

Comment: Am having svg tag .. I am using pdfjs to create annotation .

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: Am creating circle from js file using svg . Now I have to append the circle element inside <a> tag .But its not working even though I added appenChild

Comment: if you see the circle, then a tag is there.

Comment: Yes circle is there

Answer (score 3):

Your `circle` *needs* to be inside an `svg` tag, otherwise it is meaningless in your `html`. So create a wrapping SVG in the same way you make the `circle`, then append the `circle` to that, and the `svg` to your `anchor`:

```js
function createCircle( a ){

  var svg = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg' );
  var circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
  var anchor = document.createElement( 'a' );

  circle.setAttribute( 'cx', a.cx );
  circle.setAttribute( 'cy', a.cy );
  circle.setAttribute( 'r', a.r );
  
  svg.setAttribute( 'viewBox', `${a.x - a.r} ${a.y - a.r} ${a.r * 2} ${a.r * 2}` );
  svg.setAttribute( 'width', `${a.r * 2}` );
  svg.setAttribute( 'height', `${a.r * 2}` );
  
  svg.appendChild( circle );
  anchor.appendChild( svg );

  return anchor;
  
}

document.body.appendChild( createCircle({ cx: 10, cy: 10, r: 10 }) );
```

You should not add attributes such as `fill` and `stroke` to your `a` tag directly, as those attributes are not supported and invalid. You should use `data` attributes in that case. Maybe even consider just using `data-svg-attributes="{'cx':10,'cy':10,'r':10}"` and use a `JSON.parse` when you need to to get the right data out. *Update*: The `fill` and `stroke` attributes will be inherited if you declare them in the wrapping tag's `style` attribute, so you could use that (aka `style="stroke: red;"`).

Comment: "You should not add attributes such as fill and stroke... as those attributes are not supported and invalid". This advice is wrong. They are completely valid.  They won't be used by the `<a>` tag, but they *will* be inherited by the tag's child elements.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I just quickly tested this on my snippet and that is simply not true. The `style` element will be inherited, so you could use that, but the actual attributes do not inherit to the child elements.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau he's using a HTML <a> tag, not an SVG <a> tag. HTML does not have mapped CSS properties.

Comment: Alternatively you could put the <a> in the SVG as an SVG tag using createElementNS, then properties such as fill/stroke could be set as attributes. So <svg><a><circle> rather than <a><svg><circle>

Comment: @RobertLongson Thats might be true, but at that point, why would you do that? Why not use them on the appropriate tags then? Either way, the way I see this question is just to add the image afterwards, so there shouldn't be any SVG setup to work with. In that case, this won't work.

Comment: My apologies to @somethinghere. I misread the code and thought you were using an SVG `<a>`

Answer (score 3):

You are creating your `<a>` element the incorrect way.  You are using:

```
document.createElement("a")
```

This creates an `<a>` element in the HTML namespace.  In other words, an HTML `<a>` element.

You need to create an SVG `<a>` element, which is completely different, even though it has the same name.

You do that in the same way that you created the `<circle>` element:

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

appendChild, replaceNode etc will remove the node from the tree before relocating it, so (since  you asked it vaguely I have 0 idea if the atag exists or not, so I assume it is there, otherwise create it using `createElementNS`):

```
yourSvg = document.querySelector("svg");
    yourCircle = svg.querySelector("circle");
    yourATag = svg.querySelector("a");
    yourATag.appendChild(yourCircle)
```

The a tag is not a visual element, its bounding box will be equal to what is inside. In case you are wondering:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/4t44n8jo/4/

Comment: Ya, I have added like this but am having only circle

Comment: Yes <a stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" data-pdf-annotate-id="b91a7011-656c-48d6-9f1c-62ac4bfc4f91" data-pdf-annotate-type="fillcircle" aria-hidden="true" transform="scale(1.33) rotate(0) translate(0, 0)"><circle cx="138.76877404693374" cy="82.72243012162977" r="10"></circle></a>  am getting like this

Comment: I added a fiddle,  a tag is there.

Comment: The problem is you are using a html "a" tag to append your things to. This is a bad idea because the moment you want to give width and height into your svg , your document will not validate. html a tag is a phrasing element, it cannot contain any block level elements. Use the svg "a" tag instead and append this to a div in your document as I showed you in my fiddle.